# how to prevent update from being called so frequently?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, 2d

I'm making a tetris type demo using ThreeJs. For rendering, I'm using `requestAnimationFrame`. Snippet:

```js
game.prototype.render = function(){
 var thisObj = this;

 requestAnimationFrame( function() {thisObj.render();} );

 var now = new Date().getTime();
 var dt = now - (time || now);
 time = now;

 this.update(dt);

 this.boardMgr.render(dt);
 this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
};
```

this.update(dt) - calls boardMgr.update(dt)

```js
BoardMgr.prototype.update = function(dt) {
 if(this.activeBlock == null){
  this.activeBlock = this.getNextBlock();
  //console.log("letter: " + this.activeBlock.letter);
 }

 // update active block as per keyboard input
 // left/right/falldown
 // else
 {
  this.move(this.activeBlock, DIRECTION.DOWN);
 }
};
```

When I run this, the blocks are falling too fast (If I understand this correctly, update is getting called way too many times and hence the blocks are being updated as fast).

How do I control the speed of falling blocks ? Or should I not call update as frequently ? What is the correct way of handling this ?

Code can be seen here:
https://github.com/brainydexter/PublicCode/tree/master/graphics

Movement: I have a 5x5 grid-board, and I maintain a board position. So, if a block `can` move downwards, the new position is: (x, y+1). At the time of rendering, I update the position of the block in world coordinate system based on board position. So, I always move blocks in increments of BLOCK_WIDTH:

```js
BoardMgr.prototype.render = function(dt) {
 for (var i = 0; i < this.blocks.length; i++) {
  if(this.blocks[i].visible)
  {
   this.blocks[i].position.x = (this.BLOCK_WIDTH/2) + ( this.blocks[i].boardPosition.x * this.BLOCK_WIDTH);
   this.blocks[i].position.y = (this.BLOCK_WIDTH/2) + ( this.blocks[i].boardPosition.y * this.BLOCK_WIDTH);
  }
 };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT

Ah. So I'm guessing you want the blocks to snap to a grid, and have that classic jerky step down the screen. The easiest way to do this is keep the time since the last update, and only move the blocks again when this goes over a certain limit, say, 500 milliseconds.

```
// Wait times between each step
sidestep = 240;
downstep = 500;
fallstep = 80;

BoardMgr.prototype.update = function(dt) {
    this.vtimer += dt;
    this.htimer += dt;
    ...

    if ( left && this.htimer > sidestep ) {
        this.move(this.activeBlock, DIRECTION.LEFT);
        this.htimer = 0;
    }
    if ( right && this.htimer > sidestep ) {
        this.move(this.activeBlock, DIRECTION.RIGHT);
        this.htimer = 0;
    }

    if ( ( fall && this.vtimer > fallstep ) || ( this.vtimer > downstep ) ) {
        this.vtimer = 0;
        this.move(this.activeBlock, DIRECTION.DOWN);
}
};
```

If you want it to be a lot more sensitive to left and right, and not limited in sideways speed, you could do this:

```
BoardMgr.prototype.update = function(dt) {
    this.vtimer += dt;
    ...

    if ( left )
        this.move(this.activeBlock, DIRECTION.LEFT);
    if ( right )
        this.move(this.activeBlock, DIRECTION.RIGHT);

    if ( ( fall && this.vtimer > fallstep ) || ( this.vtimer > downstep ) ) {
        this.vtimer = 0;
        this.move(this.activeBlock, DIRECTION.DOWN);
}
};
```

Comment: Updated the post with more details on movement. If I want to move the blocks in chunks of `BLOCK_WIDTH`, how do I factor in `dt` ?

Comment: But if I do this do locally on `move()`, I think it will be out of sync with other parts of the game. For example, I am polling for input, and within 500 ms, user pressed LEFT twice, I would only update the block once. This will be a problem

Comment: Yes, polling will always have the possibility of missing an event. Since this is tetris though, you can give the left and right movement the same snap-to-grid behavior, and just give it a smaller timestep, so it moves sideways faster than downwards.

Comment: For most other games, I would agree with @mczepiel, but this is Tetris, and it seems like using dt for time smoothing is overkill when the game is supposed to be jerky.

Comment: Yep, all reasonable. OOC, how are you polling for user input such that you'd "miss" user input? (that's a bit of a digression of course)

Comment: If the user presses left twice here, it will only move left once. This approach is more of a "the user holds the key down until the block is in the right place" approach than a "tap left 3 times" approach.

Comment: Just edited to show a way where the chance of a key press being missed is incredibly small.

Comment: Well again, not the point of this question, but I think as a player I'd be frustrated if I tapped left twice and the game ignored one; I know both discrete taps and long holds can be handled without losing input.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'll need to scale the activity inside `boardManager.update` to actually consider the time delta since it last ran. It looks like you have most of this wired up already.

It's worth checking out general topics on game loops http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html

In short, you don't necessarily need `update` to be called less frequently, you just need to account for that and vary what you do based upon how often you're updating.

EDIT
Your render need not necessarily consider the time delta, it should simply render the state of things after `update` has updated your game state, unless you want to the smooth appearance of movement in addition to the smoothing of state updating.

But in `update` as part of gravity moving blocks, perhaps as a parameter to `move` you'll want to figure out the magnitude of your movement. You're already providing the direction, `DOWN`, so you need to figure out the rate a block drops per ms, and multiply that by the number of milliseconds in your time delta, or influence the movement however you desire for the effect you want.

User input such as moving a block left or right, for example, would likely not be influenced by time delta, but that might be a place where the rendering of a movement is considered as part of render, for smoothing a movement.Otherwise, you can simply update the position of a block immediately on input.

It's a question of the aesthetics/behavior/difficulty you're looking for. But you have all the knobs you need to dial that in how you want.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I understand render uses `dt` for animation. In the `boardMgr.update`, I want the blocks to move in the classic jerky style and snap to grid. Thus the movement is from one grid block to another and not fluid between the grid blocks. The magnitude of movement is always fixed (BLOCK_WIDTH)

Comment: Yep, if you want stepped animation you just limit updates as detailed in @andrew-williamson's answer. That's my point about how you account for the time delta and how it influences your accounting of it being up to you for various reasons. Hope you've got something working. Cheers!